# The php post is returning wrong value

Tags: php, post

I have wrote the code like this

```
<?php 
  echo "Add1:".$_POST['Address1'];
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Add2:".$_POST['Address2'];
 ?>
<FORM name="myForm" method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Address 1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Address1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Address2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Address2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit">
</FORM>
```

When enter a value as some thing like this

```
Address1 = test <test1 and Address2=address2:
```

But in post i got only the Address1 value in both post variable like.

```
Add1:test
Add2:test1
```

Any one can help me.

Comment: You do not have that problem with this form.

Comment: in your post Add1:test
Add2:test1 have different values

Answer (score 0):

Debug what you're getting via

```
<?php print_r($_POST);
```

and you'll see if it is PHP releated problem or the problem lays somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, it doesn't look like it's not working (Add1 and Add2 are different). What happens if you do a `var_dump($_POST)`?

Answer (score 0):

If `$_POST['Address2']` wasn't filled through the form, **it is empty**, no output should be displayed.

Try `var_dump($_POST);` to check the whole POST-array and/or use tools like Firebug, to see which data was sent to the actually.

Answer (score 0):

you can have exact idea by writing this code

```
<?php 
    echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";
    echo "Add1:".$_POST['Address1'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Add2:".$_POST['Address2'];
?>
```

that will emable you to check what exactly is coming in $_POST